# What is wrong with the word "performant"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, is-it-a-word, computing

I keep getting the red underlining in Word whenever I write the word "*performant*". Here I intend to refer to something that performs well or better than something else (i.e., it's more *performant*).

Is there something wrong with that word? Does it mean what I actually want it to say?

Comment: Though I've never heard it before, it seems to be a viable construction. However, it doesn't have a coherent meaning to me...I don't know what adding the suffix really means (despite what you intend it to mean).

Comment: Perhaps "performant" is jargon of a particular field.  If so, and you are writing for that field, then: either ignore the underline or teach Word to accept "performant".

Comment: I came to this discussion because I find the word *performant* being used more frequently. I believe it stems from the idea that optimal performance is due to a number of factors, not simply defined as speed or efficiency. If I say I want the fastest system, I might get fastest, but with substandard quality. Efficiency is closer, as it suggests the best use of resources for the desired result, but efficiency does suggest that a solution may be more concerned with cost over speed or quality. In my experience, *performant* suggests that there will be agreement on the appropriate tradeoffs betwee

Comment: See this talk from 12:51 onwards for good reasons to avoid the word, and a comparison with the words _efficient/efficiency_: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHNmRkzxHWs&feature=youtu.be&t=12m51s

Comment: It's jargon.  Know your audience.  If your audience is software engineers, it's fine.  If it's anyone else, then you should either find another word or explain the jargon.

Comment: I can't actually add an answer here, because I'm low on rep here apparently. But one thing I just wanted to add is that I don't think using performant as another way of saying something "performs better" is correct, I think it actually is closer to the usage of the word performative, although, instead of referring to the action, it's referring to the actor. Although, I've never heard it used in an IT setting (mostly in Gender Studies), I did manage to use it today to refer to a CMS's self identity in creating atomicity, which is sorta weird, but I think correct still (which is why I'm here).

Comment: "performant" is not a synonym for "efficient". .. one can optimize a very inefficient algorithm; the code is optimal/performant but not efficient.

Comment: I would use "better performance" or "better performing" rather than "more performant".

Comment: I have seen people use this to mean: use less computational time to perform the same computation.  This is, of course, a software jargon.  For example, I converted the face recognition code to use SSE.  It's now more performant.

Comment: The underlining of a word by a word processor should cause you to double-check the spelling and syntactic use of the word against your own memory and/or appropriate references.  If your checks tell you that you usage is legitimate you should ignore what the word processor says -- they are notorious for errant flagging, and should only be regarded as an "aide", not your stern 8th-grade English teacher.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112743/what-does-performant-software-actually-mean

Comment: @richremer: Even some of us software engineers hate this word. It sounds like using a $5 word you don't know the meaning of instead of a 50 cent word everybody knows. Is it faster? More efficient? Quicker? Or you just think it's better and a longer buzzword will convince me? Many technical people don't like fuzzy words dressed up as technical words.

Comment: “Performant” is usually used by writers and normal people shudder when they hear it. It is a buzzword that we could all do without.

Comment: Consider switching the answer to this question to [gman's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/531451/80679), which may be more up to date, as the computing adjective usage is now appearing in the [Oxford dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/performant).

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Whether or not "performant" is actually a *real* word has been debated for some time.

It does not appear in the dictionary, nor does Google definitions include it.

While it has been used before and appears in [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/performant), I would tend to avoid using it until the word becomes, well...a word.

Is there any reason you could not use one of the following instead?

> Example A performed better than Example B.

or

> Example A outperformed Example B.

Jon Galloway's blog article [Performant isn't a word](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/performant-isn-t-a-word) is an example of someone who used "performant" extensively only to be told it was not a word. While the research he did on the subject was conducted in 2007, it certainly seems to remain valid today.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82359/discussion-on-answer-by-rgw1976-what-is-wrong-with-the-word-performant).

Comment: As some other users have noted, *performant* was added to the Oxford dictionary in Dec 2018, seven years after this answer was accepted. More recent answers seem to indicate this, and anyone who wants to post a nice new clear answer should feel free to do so. OP can change their accepted checkmark (although probably won't since they haven't been here in four years), others can upvote newer answers, etc.

Answer (score 73):

I use the word *performant* often, and its meaning (in my opinion) is subtly different from that of *fast* or *efficient*. The most performant network might not be the fastest, or the most efficient, but the one which provides the best overall service.

> My IT systems are both performant and resilient.

The above seems (to me) to be very succinct. The word *performant* implies speed, accuracy, flexibility and capability — it implies that my IT systems are just right for my environment. They might not be the fastest, and not necessarily the most feature-packed, but they're just right for my needs.

I like *performant*.

Comment: Yeah, where I work (Melbourne, Australia, IT sector), "performant" seems to be very much a real word - I keep seeing and hearing it used by educated, native English speakers. Years ago I worked in the French IT sector, and kind of envied this word: it's very succinct to say "c'est performant mais pas chèr", but hard to translate exactly ("it's fast", "it's powerful", "it's efficient"...are not quite right). "Performant" is just the appropriate adjective for "high performance".

Comment: In my experience performant is widely used in software development environments, less so in general usage.

Comment: How do you _know_ what _performant_ means? Where did you look it up? Or are you just stating _your own_ interpretation, which can, and likely is, different from those of others?

Comment: This is exactly why I hate it. The people who use it don't know what they're trying to communicate. They think it means both "might not be the fastest, or the most efficient" _and_ "speed, accuracy, flexibility and capability" at the same time! It means both "it may not be better by every measurement but it's better overall" _and_ "it is better by every one of these measurements"!!

Comment: "Best overall service" has to be technically defined or else it's just a subjective opinion.  If one can technically define which qualities render a service "best overall", then why not do that instead of using the word "performant"?

Answer (score 60):

It does mean what you want to say, possibly, but it's not the clearest way of saying it.

*Performant* is being increasingly used, therefore it deserves to be considered a word. I still have misgivings about it though, largely because it seems redundant: you could instead say "fast" or "efficient".
If something's *fast*, why not just say so, instead of using the word *performant*?
And *more performant* is even sillier, when you could just say *faster*.

At the moment, it's still the sort of word you tend to see written in press releases or spoken by marketing people. To me it's a weasel-word like "premier", which sounds promising but technically meaningless and legally non-binding (what does "premier" actually mean? *First*, *biggest*, *fastest*, *best-selling* or *highest ranking sales by value*?)

The word *performant* could mean one of several things depending on the context (fast, efficient, small, optimal) and not using one of those alternative words suggests (to me) that the speaker/writer doesn't know what he's talking about, or for some reason doesn't want *me* to know what he's talking about.

Go ahead and use the word if you like, but I won't trust you, because you'll sound like a sales brochure.

Comment: By that reasoning, everyone who uses the word "better" makes them sound like a sales brochure to you. There is a trade-off between being specific and generic. When you wish to avoid specifying the details, because both speaker and listener(s) know what is intended in the given context, it is valid to use the word performant. For instance, with regard to software code, it usually means either one or a combination of: faster processing, having more optimizations, lower memory consumption, lower filesystem usage, or being low on system resources in general.

Comment: A query might be fast on database A and slow on database B. So is it slow or fast? It depends. If B is not actually a valid dataset the query will ever be expected to run on, then the query is "fast enough considering its intended use". It's performant.

Comment: And now StackExchange/Stackoverflow has jumped on the bandwagon by using this questionable word: https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/12/22/best-practices-can-slow-your-application-down/

Comment: @Yeti in some contexts, "better" is infact a very meaningless word and definitely qualifies as a "weasel word" except when casually describing one's preference IMHO. But saying something is "better" or "more performant" is equally flimsy. It's just circular reasoning if it isn't accompanied by specific criteria (in my experience, "performant" almost never is). "Better at <x>" is relatively common, but people say "performant" specifically to *avoid* saying what it's performant "at".

Comment: @DarrenRinger If you're writing a scientific paper, I might agree. But even then, you might still say A is more performant than B, while referencing to a table that has all the specific data. I feel like you're just trying to point out that the word is often misused, but that does not invalidate its use. Furthermore, there is no circular reasoning here, "performant" is clearly - albeit slightly - more specific than "better", but definitively not the other way around.

Answer (score 40):

In French, it's an actual word that means something like performs effectively, efficiently, and well. So, French students use it regularly because it sounds like English, although I'd classify it as a false cognate.

Comment: According to the french Wiktionary, the french "Performant" and its related words comes from the english's "Performance", which in turn comes from old-french "Parformance"... :-) ... https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/performance

Comment: "Performant" exists in German as well and also originates from English "Performance", which in turn became a recognized word in German in 1991. In German, something is "performant", if it has a good performance, performs well or is efficient. In no way does it imply something to be optimal.

Comment: In my opinion this is exactly the source of this annoying non-word's use. As someone who speaks fluent French (native UK English speaker) and have worked in large French companies, I have heard this used very often in French, only then to be used again in the "English" translation.

Answer (score 28):

The word **performant** is engineering jargon for something that may not be objectively efficient or optimal/fast but meets the performance expectations for which it was created. When an engineer uses the word *performant*, they mean that it's as fast and efficient as you would intuitively expect it to be. It's not meant to declare that it's the optimal or best solution, just that after working through the problem, it's the solution he settled on, and it was as fast and efficient as he expected it to be while still remaining within other project constraints.

**EDIT:** Thanks to Sven for contributing a link to [this page](http://books.google.com/books?id=FYkmwYKBoCwC&pg=PA235&dq=%22performant%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=CG4XVIydJ4XUiwKM1IDQBg&ved=0CEAQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22performant%22&f=false) where the writers associate the degree to which an entity is ***performant*** to how well they satisfy some objective. This is very much how I've seen this word used among engineers; something is deemed performant not by merely being fast but by meeting an objective for speed.

It's all about context and connotation. If I improve part of a system that will also improve performance, I might mention in a meeting that I made the part of the system *more performant*, which could mean that I made it use less memory or processor time, eliminated a redundant and expensive call, used a better algorithm, replaced an external call with an internal one, the list goes on and on. But most everyone at the meeting only cares about the result, and they'll come to me afterwards to discuss the change if they are curious.

It will probably make it into the dictionaries eventually, but in the mean time there's little reason not to use the alternatives, especially since you're writing a document. If you really do want to say something is *performant*, you can instead outline the metrics for your comparison and use a more appropriate word like other answers have suggested. On the other hand, depending on your intended audience, throwing a buzzword like "performant" in may be helpful. Just use it with care outside of engineering circles.

**For inquiring minds**:

It's easy to illustrate how the word *performant* is used in software engineering. Consider sorting a set of numbers from smallest to greatest. Every first year Computer Science student learns the [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) algorithm. It is the go-to sorting algorithm because it tends to behave optimally in practice. It has a flaw, however, that can make it abysmally slow on some lists. One of the first and simplest sorting algorithms a student is introduced to, called [Insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort), can handily beat it in some cases, even though it's usually a very bad choice of sorting algorithm (for large lists).

Which leads to a conundrum: if **performant** could be simply interchanged with **optimal** or **best**, which sorting algorithm would be *performant*: Quicksort, or Insertion sort? The answer is, *"It depends."*

It's that way with every algorithm. If you ask someone if their code is *efficient* or *fast*, the answer must always be "*It depends."* How do you define *efficient*? How do you define *fast*? And so the "made-up" or "invalid" word **performant** was born. It allows developers to state with certainty that given resource constraints and expectations, including how much time the developer was given to solve the problem, the proposed solution is **performant**. It usually implies that performance goals were taken into account, but doesn't exaggerate by saying that it is the fastest solution possible.

In some way, I think developers like to use it because the longer you write software, the humbler you become. I prefer to say that my code is *performant* (i.e. performance meets expectations) than to say that it is fast or the best way to handle something, because inevitably someone comes along and creates a way better than mine. It's the nature of engineering, all of us standing on the shoulders of giants. It may seem noncommittal, but what exactly do you say when you write something that you know will be obsolete months or years after it's written?

All of that said, whether it is a "word" by anyone's definition, I guarantee it will continue to be used in development circles, as it is not as interchangeable as people outside the field think.

Comment: Any citations or references for all this?

Comment: You make a persuasive case for the word's utility in its originating context. My only regret is that within five years it will begin a second life in MBA-speak among people who vaguely understand it to mean "good" and who misapply to it to company strategies and sales objectives.

Comment: No, I have been a computer programmer for many years and I was just describing my experience for how the word is used among my peers. Forgive me if citations are required, I'll withdraw the answer.

Comment: Actually your definition is pretty close to the one here http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/performant

Comment: @SvenYargs Agreed. It's especially disconcerting when something you casually mentioned at lunch to a business analyst suddenly ends up on an advertising pamphlet.

Comment: @MartinSmith I didn't know wiktionary counted as a reference! :)

Comment: I only pop on to this site occasionally. I have no idea what the standard is for citations!

Comment: For an example in which authors define _performant_ in connection with three levels of success (or not) in satisfying a system objective, see [this page](http://books.google.com/books?id=FYkmwYKBoCwC&pg=PA235&dq=%22performant%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=CG4XVIydJ4XUiwKM1IDQBg&ved=0CEAQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22performant%22&f=false) from Reznick, Dimitrov, and Kacprzyk, _Fuzzy System Design_, the levels being "not performant," "partially performant," and "fully performant." This, I think, is consistent with David Schwartz's description.

Comment: It is true that "performant", in a systems engineering perspective, has no obvious synonyms, and in particular, differs significantly from "optimum", "fast", "tuned", etc. I also use the word often in technical writing, and to replace it would require significant sacrifices in brevity and clarity. For example, this week I opened a trouble ticket stating, "The mail server is non-performant"; an equivalent rephrasing would have to be something like "The mail server's performance is significantly below the mandatory benchmarks stated in the relevant requirements document."

Comment: +1. It is a fantastic made up word used in DevOps circles like when doing WPO (Web performance optimization) and FEO (Front-End Optimization) and asserting something is faster and efficient overall.

Comment: How do you _know_ what _performant_ means? Did you look it up in a dictionary, or are you simply assuming its meaning?

Comment: @FrederikKrautwald This definition is based on my experience of how the word is used by myself and others in software/tech fields. Mostly I just wanted to show that it has valid uses and can't always be simply replaced by dictionary words like "optimal." AFAIK, it isn't in official dictionaries, though you can find a definition on Wiktionary: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/performant

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, the problem is that it even means different things to different people in the software or IT industry. It is impossible to deduce what a person means. Oxford dictionary says it means _functioning well or as expected_, while Cambridge says it means _working in an efficient way_. You say it also means _fast_, but fast to whom?

Comment: This is the best answer as it tried hardest to pin down the meaning. It's helped me get to what I've always hated about it. Whereas words like _fast_, _quick_, _efficient_, etc are all quantifiable, _performant_ is not. You can say you made something 10% quicker but not that you made it 10% more performant. Or else in what units? This is why I find it fuzzy and ignorant and imprecise and why I like all the words it replaces better.

Comment: @FrederikKrautwald If I say a car is _fast_, what do I mean? How fast is _fast_? Am I talking about acceleration or top speed? Better yet, if I say it handles well, what do I mean? It is in the nature of words like _performance_, _fast_, and _efficient_ that they will have different meanings depending on how, when, and where you use them. That doesn't mean they have no legitimate uses. I wholeheartedly recommend using less ambiguous language when you can, but those words can just muddy the waters when you're talking to a non-technical person, for example.

Answer (score 15):

There's not really anything inherently wrong with *performant*; its formation is regular enough and it seems to convey a meaning that no other single word conveys. If that is enough for you, then go ahead. But you ought to know that the word will be ill-regarded by many, who will consider it a pseudo-learned, affected, vulgar and pointless novelty. Of course, perhaps they are wrong about this, but even if so, they may well be people whose good opinion of your language is important to you.

Comment: +1 In my experience, the types of people who use words like "performant" don't actually care what you think of them.

Comment: ' ... it **seems** to convey a meaning that no other single word conveys' would suggest an obvious inherent problem. _How does one find what it means if it's so rare as to not make it into a dictionary?_ [It _has_ since been recognised as a neologism by an Oxford dictionary, so the major problem is now resolved.]

Answer (score 10):

I would avoid using "performant" in any formal documentation or technical report. However -- coming from the other side of the debate -- I think that there's nothing wrong with using performant.

The English language, along with all other living languages, transform regularly.  The more a word is used, the more that it will be accepted.  I would be surprised, in fact, if the word doesn't hit the dictionary soon.

As long as you're in a fairly informal situation, I see nothing wrong with using the word.  I agree to avoid it in anything formal, though.

Comment: With some misgivings, admittedly, I'm going to downvote this. Noting OP's *getting the red underlining*, I think we can assume he's not a native speaker. Whilst I'm happy to agree that English is a "living language", I'm not comfortable with telling non-native-speakers it's okay to promulgate any neologisms or idiosyncratic usages they happen to come up with.

Comment: Uhh... I'm a native speaker and I would totally use that phrase.  :P  I appreciate you're well thought out comment though.  Thank you!

Comment: Well, I'm almost a "wrinkly", and ordinarily I would totally *not* use the word "totally" like that. In general I do agree with your basic premise, particularly when there's clear semantic space waiting to be occupied by a new usage. But in this case I'd have thought existing words like *effective* and *efficient* cover the meaning, so *performant* looks like a jargon "buzzword" that should be left in whatever specialised vocabularies it's already colonised.

Comment: ...anyway, having just realised that you could justifiably resent the loss of rep there, I've just been through your other answers and upvoted everything I reasonably could. You may be glad to know there was only one other I couldn't endorse, and in several cases I thought yours was the best answer, even if it didn't have the most upvotes already.

Comment: Deciding the validity of the new word cannot be based solely on which language the prospective user learned first - this is an ad hominem argument. The decision should be based entirely upon the merit of the argument for which the usage was propounded. If we err against validity of an expression when a non-native speaker enquires, the question can still be posed by a native speaker, and if the argument itself (which in this case it is) is meritorious, then we have simply not addressed it. Also, the existence of synonyms don't preclude neologisms - if they did, synonyms wouldn't exist.

Comment: The problem is that no one _knows_ what _performant_ actually means.

Comment: As an amateur lexicographer I definitely agree it's become a word, because lots of people use it. It is a new pretentious fuzzy buzzword that gloms together several common adjectives in an unclear way. I like new jargon and technical terms, but this particular new word performs badly in this regard.

Answer (score 9):

To all the people saying that "performant" is not in the dictionary and it is not a word, I refer you to the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/262085):

> A person who performs a duty, ceremony, etc., a performer.

Of course, that doesn't help back up what you've been writing, OP, but it is quite interesting.

Personally I understand your usage of "performant" just fine – as long as your audience does too, I wouldn't worry too much what the dictionary says. Maybe it'll catch on, like busting [caps](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/25272?rskey=bEkkqX#eid252590230), [moves](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/25272?rskey=bEkkqX#eid263295617), and [rhymes](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/25272?rskey=bEkkqX#eid263295618).

Comment: How can you understand it when we have no common reference to its definition? We could use the word and have completely different interpretations or definitions of it.

Comment: Indeed, it already has a definition. _Performant_ parallels _informant_, using _-ant_ as agental suffix. Further reaching into parallels for the adjective "very much informing" leads us to _informative_ and _informatory_; and by analogy, the more correct  "very much performing" would be *_performative_ or _performatory_ -- decidedly not "performant". It aten't wot I wood of put, but if you understands it, you puts it.

Comment: The OED also recognizes the use of performant as an adjective:

"That performs or operates well; functioning at a high or sophisticated level; effective."

Answer (score 7):

I've only heard a few programmers use it.  Generally in a buzzword context to imply that a piece of software or an algorithm is "not slow."

Answer (score 7):

Dictionaries do not tell you which words are valid and which are not. They document the words people are using

[How words get added to the Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/help/#qnotin)

[How words get added to the Oxford dictionary](https://public.oed.com/how-words-enter-the-oed/)

> Words come into the English language in all manner of ways. The Oxford English Dictionary’s mission is to record all of these word stories, capturing their development as they continue to unfold.

Notice it doesn't say "tell you which words are valid". It says "record all of these words"

[How words get added to the Merriam Webster Dictionaries](https://www.merriam-webster.com/help/faq-words-into-dictionary)

> Change and variation are as natural in language as they are in other areas of human life and Merriam-Webster reference works must reflect that fact. By relying on citational evidence, we hope to keep our publications grounded in the details of current usage so they can calmly and dispassionately offer information about modern English. That way, our references can speak with authority without being authoritarian.

They are not "authoritarian" (don't tell you if a word is valid) but they are on authority on usage (this is a record of how people use this word).

So, Are people using "performant"?

Well here's [Google's developer documentation](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Adevelopers.google.com+%22performant%22) showing many uses of the word

Here's [Microsoft's usage of the word](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Amicrosoft.com+%22performant%22)

[Apple has plenty of usage](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Adeveloper.apple.com+%22performant%22)

Checking Stack Overflow it's clear [developers use this word often](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=performant)

As well as [github users](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Agithub.com+%22Performant%22)

Just searching in general brings up [19 million plus examples of usage](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22performant%22)

But if you want to claim it's not a word until some dictionary claims it is well then [it's in the Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/performant) as well as [the Oxford Dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/performant).

So, in answer to you question, nothing is wrong with the word "performant".

Comment: This should be the accepted answer now.

Answer (score 3):

Does it help, in the question of validity of the word, to have it referenced in Apple's [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/ResizableImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH30-SW1) ?

"Stretching is **performant**, but it isn’t usually desirable for a multipixel image that can distort. Tiling is less **performant** than stretching, but it's the only way to achieve a textured or patterned effect."

I had to look it up, which annoyed me, though the reasons for its use (given by @david-schwartz) are compelling.

Comment: A perfect example of how I have no idea what they're trying to say. But BUZZ!

Comment: Yep, are they saying it's more of a performance hit, or that it's less computationally intensive? I honestly cannot tell from the isolate context. The only reason I'm here is because someone wrote in a software release note "This [new feature] provides a more performant call for iterating over a list", and the imprecision led me to google it.

Comment: @hippietrail If they said "performs well" and "does not perform as well" it would avoid any "fake words" but would be no more or less informative.

Answer (score 3):

Sentences should be succinct, to the point, and should directly convey the desired meaning without ambiguity.

Performant only adds ambiguity.

For instance, what does this example sentence actually mean?

> The user interface should be highly performant.

Does that mean the interface should perform well?  As in, should it sing and dance?  Should it be minimalist?  Should it be highly responsive?  Use the precise words necessary to describe the desired outcome instead of imprecise jargon that makes you seem more interested in sounding important that in getting the work done.

See [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/180410/is-there-a-word-phrase-for-unperformant/180453#180453) for further commentary.

Answer (score 2):

Acceptance of "Performant" as a word [is a symptom of tautological references in the Software Engineering community](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22performant%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=UOA1V8u-KMTNgAaz9YroCA).

It has been in use in Software Engineering circles [since circa 1970](http://tinyurl.com/jj47ujy) is slang for "efficient" or "tuned".

To answer the OP's question, "What is wrong with [it]", well, nothing really, but the above resources demonstrate that it is software engineering slang which is seldom used in publications outside of Information Technology and so hasn't been elevated to a dictionary word.

Comment: "Optimal" means "the best". "Performant" doesn't mean that it has the best performance, only that it has good performance. Also, just because something is annoying business-speak or tech-speak, doesn't mean that it's an "invalid" word.

Comment: In addition to what Andrew said, though the question is stated as "what is wrong with performant," the implication is "why isn't this word in the dictionary." So a response of "it isn't in the dictionary" (quote: "it isn't a real word") isn't an answer. Plus, you should elaborate on this "tautologic referencing in the Software Engineering community" because you haven't given enough information for me to learn anything from your answer.

Comment: It's not in the dictionary strictly because it's "new" and has mostly been used in a restricted field. Lexicographers usually watch words for a varying length of time while evaluating them before adding them to their dictionaries. Some words go viral in a short time and get in the very next edition of the dictionary, this word is taking longer. I can guarantee it will be added sooner or later to the OED, Macquarie, Webter's, etc. Just like they all have the word "crap".

Comment: It _is_ in the dictionary, meaning "one who performs", just as _informant_ is "one who informs". So to answer the OP's question, that's what's wrong with it.  The word they're looking to coin is perhaps *_performative_, on the model of _informative_.

Answer (score 1):

The usage I've seen of Performant means meeting expectations, working adequately, or working to specifications. It does not necessarily mean efficient or most efficient, though something that is performant could also be these things.

Thus, something is either performant or not (just as one is pregnant or not), and it's inappropriate to say something is MORE performant than something else.

A problem with using this word is it's not well known and perhaps early in its development. Future usage could easily change its meaning.

Answer (score -1):

Singular synonyms may cover some cases, but they don't carry the meaning. Jon's blog tale in the accepted answer is but one of surprise and accedance. I make a case for the word *[performant](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/performant)*, and detail why in [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/490024/i-made-up-the-word-performant-has-it-occurred-in-the-english-language).