# I made up the word, "performant". Has it occurred in the English language?

Tags: meaning, synonyms, neologisms

By *[performant](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/performant)*, I mean something that performs well. A piece of computer program code could be performant, meaning that enough thought went into it to make it perform well, making it an adjective; likewise, a merchant banker could be performant, meaning his performance record monetarily is in good stature.

A close cousin would be *[abundant](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abundant)* (from *[abundance](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abundance)*).

If you describe an athlete, you're allowed to say he's fast without having to compare to any competing athlete. In the same way, it should be possible to say a person is performant - whatever his field of endeavor.

Or, indeed, his or her works, without the person involved.

The works of an artist, writer, or musician might be *[pleasant](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pleasant)*, from *[pleasance](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pleasance)*. Isn't it a fact that some professions simply measure works by performance?

Twice removed from a person, a product could be performant in a market, meaning it performs well in sales, due to any reason, not exclusively its qualities.

It seems clear that *[efficient](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/efficient)* is not a complete synonym, although I would accede it for describing a piece of computer program code's performance.

**Has it occurred in the English language, or are there existing words similar in meaning to what I described that I can use instead?**

Comment: It's already a word in several dictionaries.

Comment: You didn't make up that word. Google for it. But its a bit of managementese. You can replace it everywhere with 'efficient'

Comment: Googling it is why I'm here. :)

@Laurel: I don't know that Jon Galloway's article applies as answer to that question; mostly, it's a tale of him being surprised and accepting the "verdict". If you describe an athlete, you're allowed to say he's fast without having to bring in competition. In the same way, it should be possible to say a person is performant - whatever his field of endeavor. 

Or, indeed, his work, without the person involved. The works of an artist, writer, or musician might be flamboyant. Isn't it a fact that some professions simply measure works by their performance?

Comment: I have edited my question to detail why it's necessary, and I'll take the Cambridge definition for now. Thanks :)

Comment: Effective, effectual, operative, exemplary - I don't deny that performant is a word, but it seems like there are a few other words that have similar descriptive power.

Comment: @Mitch I guess a Ferrari at 13MPG is not very "performant" then.

Comment: @TRomano certainly not perform any if your context is fuel efficiency. Context matters for everything.